# Rails 4 I18n: Using human model name in association validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, associations

I have a simple object like:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  validates :company, presence: true
end
```

and I can't get the I18n of the validation message to use the human model name for the error message.

I have stored the key "activerecord.models.company" as "Firma" (German), and when I `Company.model_name.human`, it returns "Firma", as expected.
But it still appears as "Company" in the error message, until I store "activerecord.attributes.question.company".

This is annoying, because I need to add an attribute key for every model that validates an association with Company (i.e. "activerecord.attributes.user.company", "activerecord.attributes.project.company").

Is there any way to reference the human model name instead of the attribute?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But this reminds me to accept Alberts answer, since I think he's right about this. Don't like it though.

Comment: Thanks for checking back. It's a shame there was no solution. I ended up having to use a custom validation method so I could return a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because in your form, companies's fields depend on "has_many" relation, through fields_for helper, also using "accepts_nested_attributes" in model:

I supose you have...

in form

```
<%= question.fields_for companies do |c| %>
```

...
in model

```
class Question<ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies,  :allow_destroy => :true
```

...

I think (until now) this is normal...because companies of "Questions" can have one name, and companies of "Projects" can have another one, and so on